# Pagination in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

My question is how to give page number in jsp ex: if I have the list size is 30 on db but I want to display only 10 in page one, how to display 1 2 3 number in jsp , 30 /3,

Comment: Do i need to get list size from DB and do calculation then display number??  if yes , then my doubt is if i get list from DB , i can use the same list then what is the use of pagination

Comment: I made a GitHub [repository](https://github.com/BranislavLazic/spring-thymeleaf-pagination) for that. Take a look.

Answer (score -1):

You can use DataTable for displaying data:

The Javascript shown below is used to initialise the table shown in this example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

In addition to the above code, the following Javascript library files are loaded for use in this example:

```
//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js
```

Comment: please watch this , its a shopping App , first i want to display number in jsp according to list